# Django queries return out-of-date results in long running script using Django 1.4

Tags: python, django, orm, django-1.4

I'm using Django 1.4. My long-running script is returning the wrong results.

```
import os
import sys
sys.path.append(r'F:\my_test_project')  # my project path
os.environ['DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE'] = 'django_project.settings'
from django.conf import settings
from django_project.myapp.models import MyModel

import time

for item in xrange(1000):
    print MyModel.objects.count()
    time.sleep(5)
```

If I delete all table datas in database manually when the forloop still running, The forloop count print won't be 0 then, it still show the count print of first forloop.

Why can't I get the real count of datas when database actually changed？How can I resolve it?

Comment: Which database, and how do you delete the rows?

Comment: The script will run in a transaction so won't see any changes outside that transaction until you commit.

Comment: The database is MySQL 5.5.